# Disable click if class ="X", jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im trying to build a tabbed content box, and im wondering if its possible that i can disable 1 link with a specific class, such as 'disabled'

I read somewhere about a function called preventDefault, would this work?

http://jsfiddle.net/Ssr5W/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can disable click event by returning false. like,

```
$('#tabmenu a').click(function() {
    return !$(this).hasClass('disabled');
});
```

Also, I've updated your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ssr5W/1/

---

**EDITED**

and of course, preventDefault would work :)

```
$('#tabmenu a').click(function(e) {
    if($(this).hasClass('disabled'))
        e.preventDefault();
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ssr5W/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.disabled').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault() ;
}) ;
```

Comment: This is not exact solution if javascript dynamically toggle 'disabled' class. It'll bind click event to those tabs that has 'disabled' class in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

You can just check for the class on the element that was clicked on:

```
$('tabElement').click(function(){
    if(this.hasClass('disabled'))
        return;
    //Your code here..
);
```

This won't interfere with other clikc-handlers you may have on your tab element